# Windows 10 and windows phone silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windowsphone, windows-10-mobile

Несколько вопросов в преддверии выхода Windows 10:

1. Будет ли приложение Windows Phone Silverlight запускаться в Windows 10? Если да, то какая версия Silverlight подойдет? (для 7.1, для 8.0)
2. Будет ли Silverlight приложение доступно в общем магазине?
3. Целевые устройства для нашего приложения - смартфоны (как показывает статистика с других систем - даже планшеты практически не используются) Если ответы на первые два вопроса утвердительные, то какими аргументами убедить босса перейти на winrt? И стоит ли убеждать?

Comment: А что техническая поддержка Windows говорят по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1):

В долгосрочной перспективе однозначно нужно переходить на WinRT, а лучше сейчас, Вы только отсрочиваете этот переход, в конце концов майки откажутся от поддержки silverlight что приведет Вас в расплох

Answer (score 0):

1. на текущий момент(01.11.2016) все приложения, когда-либо написанные для мобильнйо платформы Microsoft обратно совместимы. Но, как замечено выше, с большой долей вероятности так будет не всегда.
2. Будет
3. - Более продвинутое API
   - Гарантия непрекращения поддержки в самый ножиданный момент
   - Современные средства разработки UI(сделать условный "гамбургер" на Silverlight не так то просто)